# Weird behaviour with assignment in python

Tags: python

I am getting weird behavior in a snippet of code which I can't explain. I create two variations of a function which both manipulate a dictionary. But only one of these actually alters the values of the dictionary.

Consider the following function :

```
def change(batch):
    w = batch[4]
    for i in range(5):
        w += batch[i]
    
    return w
```

If we set `batch = dict(zip(range(5),[5 + np.random.randn(5)]*5))` then calling change(batch), alters the value of batch i.e. the function modifies the element batch[4].

However, if we modify the function to

```
def change(batch):
    w = batch[4]
    for i in range(5):
        w = w + batch[i]
    
    return w
```

then calling change(batch) does not alter the original batch. Does anyone know why ?